# Call HelperResult from javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a treeview on a view in mvc and when a user clicks one of the items I want to load a partial view to the right of the main treeview

I have a a helperresult inside a div that should load the view, but when I call it like this it just freezes the treeview and I cannot click any items.

Here is what I am trying

```
                @helper RenderFirst()
                {
                    <div class="treeview-back">                        
                            @Html.Action("Results", "Results");                        
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</div>

<script>
    var treeview;
    var siteSelect = "Result1";

    function onSelect(e) {
        if (this.text(e.node) == siteSelect) {         
                @RenderFirst();
        } else {
            alert('false');
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    });
</script>
```

if i replace @RenderFirst(); with this alert('true') it is fine.

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 with VS 2012 C#

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing server-side code with JavaScript which can't work. You should either use jQuery to insert the `div` element or render it when loading the page (make it invisible initially), then in `onSelect`:

```
$(".treeview-back").show();
```